# How to send ERC20 token using web3 library

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc20

I want to implement a send ERC20 token function in my crypto wallet, and this is the function that I found on the internet shown as below.

```
 sendToken()
  {
    let toAddress = "0x5077174D79d9491AF15Dcf7D1496638D6062A011";
    this.tokenContractInstance.transfer(toAddress,123, (error, result) => {
      if (error == null) {
        console.log(result)

      } else {
        console.log('Transfer error' + error)
      }
    })
  }
```

Unfortunately, no luck for me with error message

> "Invalid Message"

May I know why is failed? Also, I have seen others example as well to send ERC20 token by generating the rawTransaction with the privateKey sign function. Which approach should I go with?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming web3 1.0, this is the correct way:

```
this.tokenContractInstance.methods.transfer(toAddress, 123).send({from: txSenderAddress}, (error, transactionHash) => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I use the method above and I got an error message ("Invalid Address")

Comment: @ferit- Instead, of this.tokenContractInstance.methods.transfer, I changed to this this.tokenContractInstance.transfer. The first method doesn't works for me, it says, the transfer function not found.

Comment: @ferit- Why is that your code above shown as methods.transfer? Isn't it the transfer function straight from the contract instance? Maybe, worth to mention here, I'm using the web3 version 0.19.1.

Comment: I'm just wondering, the sender address is not the original ERC20 owner account. The address is the second transferred account from the original owner, in this case, wondering do I need to get the owner's approval to spend the token or transfer?

Comment: Yeah @DavidB I was assuming you are using web3 1.0. I recommend that you use too, because web3 0.x is too old.

Comment: @ferit- I agree that the version 0.19.x is old. But, consider that the entire project framework design and dependencies, we cannot afford to make the change now. Could you advise on the version 0.19.x?

Comment: In this case, I suppose, to construct a RawTransaction message to send the ERC20 token will be ideal?

Comment: @ferit- Even I try on the web3 version 1.x and I got this error message below. Node error: {"code":-32601,"message":"The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available"}

Comment: @DavidB Debug your contract instance. Maybe the instance is wrong.

Comment: @ferit- I don't think in this case, the contract instance could be the root cause. Because, I have done a test on local machine Ganache and it was working fine. Only, when I test on Ropsten network then it gives me the "code-32601" error message.

Comment: I strongly recommend to upgrade to web3.

Comment: @ferit- Alright, any specific version would you recommend? web3 1.x?

Comment: @ferit- I can see the transfer method is there. I have no idea why it throwing me the "eth_sendTransaction method not found".

Comment: @ferit- Did you try that successfully on Ropsten via Infura? In my case, the environment is Ropsten and Infura.

Comment: Well, why don't you try to use another blockchain to isolate the issue? You should be doing this yourself. Try Kovan for example. @DavidB

Comment: Thank you for your advised and your precious time much appreciated